# How create a button list for react-navigation with react-native and redux?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I programmed a working react-native-example with navigation and redux and placed it under https://github.com/matthiaw/react-native-redux-example/tree/master.

I have a goal in mind and for that i need a lot more functionality, but i am new to react and react-native, so i try hours of moving forward. But i like react and take my time. But now i get stucked because i want to iterate over a json-list of "Buttons" with different Route-Goals and a specific params.

My problem is that i am not able to replace the inner method

```
navigateRoles = () => {
  const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: "roles",
    params: { name: "Parameter Roles" }
  });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
};
```

with a function like

```
buttonNavigator (routeParam, nameParam) {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
       routeName: routeParam,
       params: { name: nameParam }
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}
```

which i can use like

```
<Button label="Rollen" routeParam="roles" nameParam="Parameter Roles" />
```

I always get exception that "this" is a reserved word or other red-screens in expo which correlate to the dispatch. Also i got the problem that the navigation is excecuted on App-Start when i place the function. I like to add this method to Button-Component where the onPress works only on pressing the button.

Can you help me to learn how i can solve this?

Comment: Can you share the json structure of the list of buttons you want to loop through?

Comment: Sure. This should be `{
   "buttons":[
      {
         "label":"Settings",
         "route":"settings",
         "param":"set"
      },
      {
         "label":"Rollen",
         "route":"roles",
         "param":"view"
      },
      {
         "label":"Aufgaben",
         "route":"tasks",
         "param":"sorted"
      },
      {
         "label":"Events",
         "route":"events",
         "param":"none"
      }
   ]
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a lot of trial and error until i found a solution which works without any exception. You can find a full working example at https://github.com/matthiaw/react-native-redux-example/blob/master/src/Components/home.js.

What worked for the button-data

```
var data = JSON.parse(`{
"buttons": [
  {
    "label": "Rollen",
    "description" : "Eine Liste aller Rollen",
    "route": "roles",
    "param": "Roles Param (Iterated)"
  },
  {
    "label": "Einstellungen",
    "description" : "Einstellungen von Circlead",
    "route": "settings",
    "param": "Settings Param (Iterated)"
  },
  {
    "label": "Leer",
    "description" : "Eine leere Seite",
    "route": "empty",
    "param": "Empty Param (Iterated)"
  }
]
}`);
```

was the component

```
class Button extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={Styles.circleadMainMenuItem}
    onPress={ this.props.onPress }
  >
  <Text style={Styles.circleadMenuTitle}>
    {this.props.label}
  </Text>
  <Text style={Styles.circleadMenuDescription}>
    {this.props.description}
  </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
)
}
}
```

with

```
renderButton(button, navigation) {
return (
  <Button key={button.label} label={button.label+" (Iterated)"} description="Liste aller Rollen" onPress={ () => {
    const param = button.param;
    const route = button.route;
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route,
      params: { name: param }
    });
    navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  }} />
)
}
```

which can be used with

```
{ data.buttons.map(button => this.renderButton(button, this.props.navigation)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

About the button being pressed when you start the app, instead of calling the function directly inside the onPress, make it an arrow function.

```
<Button title="ButtonOne" onPress={ console.log("Hello") }/>
<Button title="ButtonTwo" onPress={ () => console.log("World") }/>
```

In the above example, the first button action will be called as soon as the component is loaded, but the second button onPress function is called only when that button is clicked.

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example where i pass two or three parameters to the inner arrow function? I tried this, but i always get an exception because of `NavigationActions`. This is imported globally (see code), but it did somehow not work in the arrow-function.

Comment: `<Button title="ButtonTwo" onPress={ (<placePropsHere>) => console.log("World") }/>`